# How to avoid CA2100 with a constructed query

Tags: c#, code-analysis

In many places in my code I'm building a SQL statement using StringBuilder, and in every case this triggers a `CA2100: Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities` from Code Analysis, because the SQLCommand contents come from the StringBuilder rather than a literal.

Often these queries are assembled via some flow control (case or if), where pieces of the query might be conditional.

My question is, should I suppress every single one of these, or is there a different pattern for building (sometimes complex) queries inline, but avoiding the warning?

An example of code which triggers this:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine("select ");
sb.AppendLine("  Q.QUOTE_TITLE as [@Description] ");
sb.AppendLine("from ");
sb.AppendLine("  QUOTE Q ");
sb.AppendLine("where ");
sb.AppendLine("  Q.QUOTE_ID = @QUOTE_ID ");
sb.AppendLine("  and Q.QUOTE_VERS = @QUOTE_VERS  ");
sb.AppendLine("for xml path('Contract') ");

SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), MainDBConnection);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@QUOTE_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = QuoteID;
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@QUOTE_VERS", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = QuoteVersion;
```

Comment: In the example above you can construct the whole query using single string litersal. In more complex cases (e.g. where clause contents depends on some parameters) you alternative could be some magic with `String.Format`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you use a `StringBuilder` at all? You can use a string literal which is also more readable:

```
string sql = @"select Q.QUOTE_TITLE as [@Description]
               from QUOTE Q
               where Q.QUOTE_ID = @QUOTE_ID
               and Q.QUOTE_VERS = @QUOTE_VERS
               for xml path('Contract')"; 
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, MainDBConnection);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@QUOTE_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = QuoteID;
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@QUOTE_VERS", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = QuoteVersion;
```